# Parity error not always being detected in serial port

Tags: c#, .net-core, serial-port

I have a serial port class in netcore - it just listens to the port and tries to detect parity errors. Parity is set to space, and all incoming bytes are being sent with parity=mark which should result in a parity error.
Unfortunately, this is being detected only about a 1/3 of times. I need this detection because this is how the protocol states the beginning of a message.
bytes (80 and 81) are being sent every 1 second so the buffer should always have 1 byte.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// Use this code inside a project created with the Visual C# > Windows Desktop > Console Application template.
// Replace the code in Program.cs with this code.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using SASComms;

public class PortChat
{
    static bool _continue;
    static SASSerialPort _serialPort;
    static object msgsLock = new object();
    static Queue<byte[]> msgs = new Queue<byte[]>();
    static Queue<byte> receiveQeue = new Queue<byte>();
    public static void Main()
    {
        string name;
        string message;
        StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);

        // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
        _serialPort = new MachineSerialPort();

        // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
        _serialPort.PortName = "COM2";
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
        _serialPort.ParityReplace = (byte)'\0' ;
        _serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 128;
        _serialPort.Parity = Parity.Space;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        // Set the read/write timeouts
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 5;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 5;
        _serialPort.ErrorReceived +=  new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(sp_SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler);

        _serialPort.Open();
        _continue = true;
        readThread.Start();
    }

    public static void sp_SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(Object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EventType == SerialError.RXParity)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parity error");
        }
    }

    public static void Read()
    {
        while (_continue)
        {
            try
            {

                    while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                     receiveQeue.Enqueue((byte)_serialPort.ReadByte());
                }

                if (receiveQeue.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (byte r in receiveQeue)
                    {
                        Console.Write(r.ToString("X")+" " );
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                receiveQeue.Clear();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }
    }
}
```

The console is outputing this:

```
80
Parity error
81
80
Parity error
81
Parity error
80
Parity error
81
80
Parity error
81
80
81
80
81
Parity error
80
Parity error
81
80
Parity error
```

And I'm expecting "Parity error" after each byte.

Comment: Your code seems to have mis-matched braces.

Comment: I don't understand your question. [The documentation seems crystal clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.errorreceived) on how parity errors are handled (or not): _**"Because the operating system determines whether to raise this event or not, not all parity errors may be reported"**_. That's not even counting the fact that the error event is raised asynchronously, and so there's _never_ any guarantee of a 1-to-1 correlation between a byte value written to the console and the error message written to the console.

Comment: Hi @PeterDuniho thanks for referencing the documentation. Unfortunatelly the statement is there but not crystal clear at all. There's no explanation about what is the criteria used by the OS for raising the event or not. Is this totally in black-box and untouchable?

Comment: it says "the operating system determines" not "the operating system plays dices"
A criteria must be used for "determining" something and that criteria should be part of the documentation.

Comment: If I start two tasks to run concurrently, the operation system determines which order program statements in those tasks should execute relative to each other. By your logic, the documentation should include a complete description of the thread scheduler component of the OS, in a way that allows the reader to predict in what order the statements in their two tasks will execute? Uh...no. That's not how it works. You cannot expect the .NET documentation to provide you every detail of how an underlying OS might work, especially since each OS is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved much better result by moving the read logic into the SerialError handler.
Removed the Read() function and the readThread thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I was getting only 30-50% of Mark bytes being flagged with parity errors. In my case the problem was the USB RS-232 Serial cable I was using. When I switched to true RS-232 over a DB-9 cable the serial errors were raised 100% correctly.